# What is the role of "at" in this case?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

I came across this on NYTimes:

"New Orleans Saints (5-9) at Cleveland Browns (6-8), 1 p.m., CBS"

source:

https://www.nytimes.com/2022/12/22/sports/football/nfl-week-16-picks.html

I don't get the use of "at" in this case, sounds like:

New Orleans Saints is playing in a field named Cleveland Browns

Comment: to **play at a stadium**. Not in.

Answer (score 3):

In US and UK football/soccer journalism, a match can be compactly  listed or mentioned as 'Team A **at** Team B'. When this is done, 'at Team B' means 'at the home stadium or ground of Team B'.

The Cleveland Browns' home stadium is the FirstEnergy Stadium in Cleveland, Ohio, USA, and that is where this game will be played. The New Orleans Saints team and a lot of their fans will travel to Cleveland.

Possibly not every reader will be instantly aware of the location of the FirstEnergy Stadium, but every reader will understand what 'at Cleveland Browns' means.